# Added AudioFileClose to prevent running out of file handles

Tags: audio, finch

I encountered a problem using Finch - I was opening and releasing again alot of sound files and a particular point in the project sounds would stop loading - the error code form ALOpenFileFromURL... was 43 - File not found ...
my solution in the end was to make sure that files were closed by adding AudioFileClose (and keeping a record of the fileId) to the dealloc in Sound.m...
my solution is probably not graceful and maybe naive but seems to work for now - so i thought i would post in case it helps anybody else

thanks,
Ross

Answer (score 0):

That was a bug, nice catch! Thanks for reporting, it’s fixed in the current version. Next time you can report the bug directly to the [bug tracker](http://github.com/zoul/Finch/issues), it will be noticed sooner.